# return generic type from java method

Tags: java, generics

I want my Java method to return a generic T.  I can't get it to work.  My method executes a passed in method on a threadpool executor and waits for the result via a Future.get(), I want to pass the result back and this result can be different depending on the method passed in on the Supplier.

This is what I have, it works but I need to cast to the correct type when using.  I would prefer using a T t style instead of the Object.

```
   public Object executeThis(Supplier<T> request) throws RejectedExecutionException {
    Object obj = null;

    try {
        Future future = executor.submit(() -> request.get());
        obj = future.get(timeoutInMilis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a full [mcve] and provide the error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a generic type :

```
public <T> T executeThis(Supplier<T> request){}
```

You just need to declare generic type before the return type inside diamond operator , then declare the method return type (T)

You have to modify this :

```
Future future = executor.submit(() -> request.get());
obj = future.get(timeoutInMilis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

to :

```
Future<T> future = executor.submit(() -> request.get());
T obj = future.get(timeoutInMilis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Eric, very clear and precise answer. One thing I failed to mention was that my method executeThis was in a class declared like this.     MyExecuterClass<T>    so I also had to remove the <T>  bit then your answer worked.

Comment: I assume you meant `T obj = future.get` rather than just `T = future.get`.